# Nuxt Middleware: dynamic redirect and add params?

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, vue-router, middleware, nuxt.js

I have the following middleware in a page component:

```js
async middleware ({store, redirect, params}) {
    console.debug('Slug Middleware called with', params)
    if (params.wasSlugified === true) return
    let {slug, id} = await wrangleProjectSlug({slug: params.slug})
    if (slug === 0) {
      console.debug(`${params.slug} can not be identified as a porject`)
      redirect('/')
    }
    console.debug('Slug Middleware', {id, slug})
    params.id = id
    params.slug = slug
    params.wasSlugified = true

    redirect((to)=>{
      const {hash, params, query} = to
      params.id = id
      params.slug = slug
      params.wasSlugified = true
      return {path: `/project/${slug}`}
    })
  },
```

where the function `wrangleProjectSlug` takes the param `params.slug` from the page `project/_slug.vue` and uses some fuzzy string matching to redirect to the proper page name.

Since that page will also call the middleware, I would like it to add a param `wasSlugified` to prevent infinite redirects.

How can I achieve this?